# Removing duplicated functions in two classes in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns, dry

I have wrote the following code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
class ProxyiOSUIElementWrapper(val app: SIMIAppUIElementProtocol) : IAppUIElement {

    override fun tap() {
        app.tap()
    }

    override fun elementWithTestId(testId: String): IAppUIElement {
        return ProxyiOSUIElementWrapper(app.elementWithTestIdTestId(testId))
    }

    override fun table(withId: String): IAppUIElement {
        return ProxyiOSUIElementWrapper(app.tableWithId(withId))
    }

    override fun cell(withId: String): IAppUIElement {
        return ProxyiOSUIElementWrapper(app.cellWithId(withId))
    }

    override fun waitForExistence(timeout: Double) {
        app.waitForExistenceTimeout(timeout)
    }

    override fun hasText(text: String, timeout: Double) {
        app.hasTextText(text, timeout)
    }

    override fun getText(timeout: Double): String {
        return app.getTextTimeout(timeout)
    }

    override val debugDescription: String
        get() = app.debugDescription
}

class ProxyiOSAppWrapper : IAppWrapper {

    private val app = ConcreteAppWrapper(AppSetup.identifier)

    override var identifier: String = app.identifier

    override fun launch(arguments: Map<String, String>) {
        app.launchArguments(arguments as Map<Any?, *>)
    }

    override fun tap() {
        app.tap()
    }

    override fun elementWithTestId(testId: String): IAppUIElement {
        return ProxyiOSUIElementWrapper(app.elementWithTestIdTestId(testId))
    }

    override fun table(withId: String): IAppUIElement {
        return ProxyiOSUIElementWrapper(app.tableWithId(withId))
    }

    override fun cell(withId: String): IAppUIElement {
        return ProxyiOSUIElementWrapper(app.cellWithId(withId))
    }

    override fun waitForExistence(timeout: Double) {
        app.waitForExistenceTimeout(timeout)
    }

    override fun hasText(text: String, timeout: Double) {
        app.hasTextText(text, timeout)
    }

    override fun getText(timeout: Double): String {
        return app.getTextTimeout(timeout)
    }

    override val debugDescription: String
        get() = app.debugDescription
}

actual object AppSingleton {
    actual var app: IAppWrapper = ProxyiOSAppWrapper()
}
```

As you can see, there are functions that are being repeated, for example `table`, `cell` etc. How can I make it DRY? I want to take out these functions out of the classes and only write then once, but since both classes have to conform interfaces, I cannot do that. I tried creating one class that would inherit from both interfaces, but then there is a problem with constructors as one Proxy class takes an argument and the other does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a class, that would inherit from both interfaces: both IAppWrapper and IAppUIElement and override methods there. I am pasting the code below:

```kotlin
open class ProxyFunctionsHelper : IAppUIElement,
    IAppWrapper {

    private val app: Any

    constructor(app: SIMIAppUIElementProtocol) {
        this.app = app
    }

    constructor(app: ConcreteAppWrapper) {
        this.app = app
    }

    override val identifier: String
        get() = run(
            forAppWrapper = { it.identifier },
            forUIElementWrapper = { error("unable to cast app - identifier error") }
        )

    override fun launch(arguments: Map<String, String>) =
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { it.launchArguments(arguments as Map<Any?, *>) },
            forUIElementWrapper = { error("unable to cast app - launch error") }
        )

    override fun tap() =
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { it.tap() },
            forUIElementWrapper = { it.tap() }
        )

    override fun elementWithTestId(testId: String): IAppUIElement =
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { ProxyFunctionsHelper(it.elementWithTestIdTestId(testId)) },
            forUIElementWrapper = { ProxyFunctionsHelper(it.elementWithTestIdTestId(testId)) }
        )

    override fun table(withId: String): IAppUIElement =
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { ProxyFunctionsHelper(it.tableWithId(withId)) },
            forUIElementWrapper = { ProxyFunctionsHelper(it.tableWithId(withId)) }
        )

    override fun cell(withId: String): IAppUIElement =
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { ProxyFunctionsHelper(it.cellWithId(withId)) },
            forUIElementWrapper = { ProxyFunctionsHelper(it.cellWithId(withId)) }
        )

    override fun waitForExistence(timeout: Double) {
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { it.waitForExistenceTimeout(timeout) },
            forUIElementWrapper = { it.waitForExistenceTimeout(timeout) }
        )
    }

    override fun hasText(text: String, timeout: Double) {
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { it.getTextTimeout(timeout) },
            forUIElementWrapper = { it.getTextTimeout(timeout) }
        )
    }

    override fun getText(timeout: Double): String =
        run(
            forAppWrapper = { it.getTextTimeout(timeout) },
            forUIElementWrapper = { it.getTextTimeout(timeout) }
        )

    override val debugDescription: String
        get() = run(
            forAppWrapper = { it.debugDescription },
            forUIElementWrapper = { it.debugDescription }
        )

    private fun <T> run(
        forAppWrapper: (ConcreteAppWrapper) -> T,
        forUIElementWrapper: (SIMIAppUIElementProtocol) -> T
    ): T =
        when (val application = app) {
            is ConcreteAppWrapper -> forAppWrapper(application)
            is SIMIAppUIElementProtocol -> forUIElementWrapper(application)
            else -> error("unable to cast app - error")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin doesn't support **multiple inheritance** i.e., a class **cannot** inherit from two classes. However, a class can implement multiple interfaces. Review the architecture again if you want to dry out the functions in just one class. For example, below architecture **is** allowed: Class E implements interface A, B and inherits from only Class C.

```
interfaceA(){
}
interfaceB(){
}
class C(){
}
class D(){
}
class E():A,B,C{
}
```

Whereas below architecture is **not** allowed: Class E implements interfaces A, B and classes C, D.

```
interfaceA(){
}
interfaceB(){
}
class C(){
}
class D(){
}
class E():A,B,C,D{
}
```